# Catch the side slide effect on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, slide, tablet, effect

Is it possible, by jQuery or alike, to catch (detect) the finger side slide that is possible on fx an iPad?

It would be nice to be able to make an `onFingerSideSlide` effect to change page or something like that on a website, when it is viewed on an iPad or tablet. If the possibility exists it could be fun to try something creative.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several jQuery plugins made for this purpose.

SwipeJs is a good one. Find it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/).

Go to [SwipeJS.com](http://SwipeJS.com) on your iPad to try it out.